# Core Data save() Called unrecognized selector "count"

Tags: core-data

I encountered "[CDIRunningDuration count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001a0fed0" error when calling `save()` in Core Data. The model was very simple and I didn't know why.

```swift
private func runTest() {
        let session = CDISession(context: moc)
        session.startDate = Date()
        
        let app = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!
        let runningApp = CDIApp(context: moc)
        runningApp.bundleURL = app.bundleURL
        
        let runningDuration = CDIRunningDuration(context: moc)
        runningDuration.app = runningApp
        runningDuration.timelength = 100.0
        runningDuration.session = session
        
        try! moc.save()
    }
```

The full sample is here. [Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/se6lefmmqjof6nb/Core%20Data%20Issue.zip?dl=0)

--- more code ---

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var moc
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Hello World!")
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear(perform: runTest)
    }
    
    private func runTest() {
        let session = CDISession(context: moc)
        session.startDate = Date()
        
        let app = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!
        let runningApp = CDIApp(context: moc)
        runningApp.bundleURL = app.bundleURL
        
        let runningDuration = CDIRunningDuration(context: moc)
        runningDuration.app = runningApp
        runningDuration.timelength = 100.0
        runningDuration.session = session
        
        try! moc.save()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Core_Data_IssueApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, ModelProvider.shared.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreData
import AppKit

class ModelProvider:ObservableObject {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
    
    private init() {
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                let alert = NSAlert(error: error)
                NSSound.beep()
                alert.runModal()
            }
        }
    }
    
    static let shared = ModelProvider()
}
```

Comment: Where does `moc` come from, how where is it declared? Do you have an inverse relationship set up between the entities? Are you using any derived attributes?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You can know all your questions from the sample project. It has the whole project to debug with.

Comment: All relevant information should be included in the question itself, we should not have to download material from external sources to be able to understand the question.

Comment: I don't think so. For Core data. they are model descriptions. It will be too many screenshots. And many small files. I don't think anyone could solve this issue without debuging the project.

Comment: @OwenZhao When asking a question here, you should try to make it as easy as possible for people to help you. Expecting them to download and debug projects directly contradicts that idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be caused by a bug in the Model editor. To solve this, perform these steps:

- Select relationship **runningDuration > app**
- Temporarily change Type to **To Many**
- Disable "Ordered"
- Change Type back to **To One**

This kind of difficult to find errors occurs when certain properties in the Model designer disappears when changing certain settings (in this case relationship Type), but remain part of the model.

Comment: I am afraid not. They were not runningDurations<>app, just runningDuration<>app. So to one was intended.

Comment: Thank you. I believe you were right. There must be something wrong in Xcode. I removed the relationships, runningDuration <> app, on both side and created them again.  Then the code worked.